# Can i prevent any kind of animations and queuing inside a div? jQuery

Tags: jquery

Can i prevent any kind of animations and queuing inside a unique div, but allowing animations and queuing in other divs and elements?

For example:

```
<div id="uniquediv">
    <ul>
        <li>Header1
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Header 2
            <ul>
                <li>Item 1</li>
                <li>Item 2</li>
                <li>Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: menu example]

If, supposedly, this works like a SlideDown and SlideUp menu, but i want to prevent it from SlidingUp and SlidingDown. Like freezing, regardless of a menu being collapsed or not.

Comment: There is no way to stop an element from being animated, if that's what you mean. You can exclude elements you don't want to animate by the `not()` method (or `:not()` selector), although more detail and some code in your question would help a lot.

Comment: After adding the code and image, could you elaborate on why you want to block animations, specifically? Do you have no control over the animations, or are you trying do something crazy like a `.slideDown()` to toggle instead of animate?

Answer (score 1):

You could stop all animations currently running with `$('#container').find('*').addBack().stop(true,true)` (which is not very elegant).

There is no way to prevent an animation on certain objects because the animations in jQuery are centralized and can be applied to anything that can be part of a jQuery collection.

By the sound of it you should revise your script and try finding a more elegant solution to your problem in general, like excluding crucial elements from your selectors, or introducing special selectors for animated elements in general.

Maybe adding a few classes to a list of relevant elements will help. So you can animate `$('.odd span')` instead of `$('.row span')`, for example.